# javascript not redirecting to a different html page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a login for a mock site, there are 2 types of users, and each type must be redirected to its own profile page after being logged in.

However, it's only working for one type (Instructor), the other one isn't being redirected and the console isn't giving me any errors

heres the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        <title>Proyecto Final</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style3.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="conteiner cf">
                <img src="images/logo2.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
                <nav>
                    <a href="index.html">Usuario</a>
                <!--    <a href="#">About</a> -->
                    <a href="contact.html">Instructor</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>


            <div class="conteiner2 cf">

                <aside class="Texto cf">
                    <h1 class="h1texto">Usuario</h1>


                        <form class="login-form">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="txtUsername"/>

                          <input type="password" placeholder="Password"id="txtPassword"/>

                          <input type="button" value="Ingresar" id="btnIngresarLogin">


                          <p class="message">Estas registrado? <a href="register 2.html">Crear una nueva cuenta</a></p>
                        </form>

                </aside>

            </div>


    <footer class="footerfinal cf">
            <div class="conteinerfooter cf">
                <p class="ParrafoFooter cf">2014 copyright</p>
                <nav class="NavFooter">
                    <a href="#">Index</a>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </nav>
            </div>

    </footer>
    <script src="js/logicaNegociosUsuarios.js"></script>
    <script src="js/logicaInterfazInicioSesion.js"></script>

    </body>


</html>
```

and the JS

```
document.querySelector('#btnIngresarLogin').addEventListener('click', IniciarSesion);

function IniciarSesion(){
  var sUsername ='';
  var sPassword ='';
  var bAccesoInstructor = false;
  var bAccesoCliente = false;

  sUsername = document.querySelector('#txtUsername').value;
  sPassword = document.querySelector('#txtPassword').value;


  bAccesoInstructor = validarCredenciales(sUsername, sPassword);
  bAccesoCliente = validarCredenciales(sUsername, sPassword)  

  if (bAccesoInstructor === true){
    window.location.href = 'perfilInstructor.html';
  } else {
      if(bAccesoCliente === true) {
          window.location.href = 'perfilCliente.html';
      }
  }

}

function validarCredenciales(psUsername, psPassword){
  var listaUsuarios = obtenerListaUsuarios();
  var bAccesoInstructor = false;
  var bAccesoCliente = false;
  var usuario = obtenerListaUsuarios().map(function (usuario) {
    if(usuario[10] === psUsername){
      if(usuario[11] === psPassword){
         if(usuario[13] === 'Instructor') 
        bAccesoInstructor = true;
        localStorage.setItem('rolUsuarioActivoLS', JSON.stringify(usuario));
      }
    }
   else{ if(usuario[10] === psUsername){
      if(usuario[11] === psPassword){
          if(usuario[13] === 'Cliente')
              bAccesoCliente = true;
                localStorage.setItem('rolUsuarioActivoLS', JSON.stringify(usuario))
      }
   }
  }
      });

  if(!bAccesoInstructor && !bAccesoCliente){
    alert('Credenciales incorrectos');
  } 


  return bAccesoInstructor;
  return bAccesoCliente;
}
```

I even tried turning all the "bAccesoCliente" to true to see if it would go there by default but it's still not working

Comment: Having a return directly after another return is pointless, the second one will never be reached, your function is always going to return bAccesoInstructor

Comment: `return bAccesoInstructor;
return bAccesoCliente;`

two returns, the first one will be the one to be returned. that's why its return`bAccesoInstructor` and re-direct to instructor

Answer (score 0):

First, these two are wrong:

```
return bAccesoInstructor;
return bAccesoCliente;
```

A single function cannot return twice, it will never reach the 2nd return statement.

For redirection try:

```
function validarCredenciales(psUsername, psPassword){
  var listaUsuarios = obtenerListaUsuarios();
  var pageToRedirect = false;
  var usuario = obtenerListaUsuarios().map(function (usuario) {
    if(usuario[10] === psUsername && usuario[11] === psPassword){ 
         if(usuario[13] === 'Instructor') {
              pageToRedirect = 'bAccesoInstructor';
              localStorage.setItem('rolUsuarioActivoLS', JSON.stringify(usuario));
         } else if(usuario[13] === 'Cliente') {
              pageToRedirect = 'bAccesoCliente';
              localStorage.setItem('rolUsuarioActivoLS', JSON.stringify(usuario))
         }
     }
  });

  if(!pageToRedirect){
    alert('Credenciales incorrectos');
  } 
  return pageToRedirect;
}
```

Then:

```
 function IniciarSesion(){
    var sUsername ='';
    var sPassword ='';

    sUsername = document.querySelector('#txtUsername').value;
    sPassword = document.querySelector('#txtPassword').value;


    var validatedCredentials = validarCredenciales(sUsername, sPassword); 

   if (validatedCredentials ==='bAccesoInstructor'){
     window.location.href = 'perfilInstructor.html';
   } else if(validatedCredentials ==='bAccesoCliente') {  
      window.location.href = 'perfilCliente.html';
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the two return failure. However, this method is still not working, it's only redirecting to the instructor page

Comment: @IsaacG Can you post a sample of the data returned by `obtenerListaUsuarios();` function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solutions provided. However, in the end these didn't work. My cousin helped me find a simpler solution, posting it here in case anyone needs it

```
document.querySelector('#btnIngresarLogin').addEventListener('click', IniciarSesion);

function IniciarSesion(){
  var sUsername ='';
  var sPassword ='';
  var sPrivilegios = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('rolUsuarioActivoLS'))


  sUsername = document.querySelector('#txtUsername').value;
  sPassword = document.querySelector('#txtPassword').value;

  validarCredenciales(sUsername, sPassword);
}

function validarCredenciales(psUsername, psPassword){
  var listaUsuarios = obtenerListaUsuarios();
  var bAcceso = false;
  var usuario = obtenerListaUsuarios().map(function (usuario) {
    if(usuario[10] === psUsername){
      if(usuario[11] === psPassword){
        bAcceso = true;
        //Almaceno el usuario activo en LS
        localStorage.setItem('rolUsuarioActivoLS', JSON.stringify(usuario));
        if (bAcceso === true){ //Si el acceso es correcto
          if(usuario[13] === 'Cliente'){//Si el usuario es tipo cliente
            window.location.href = 'perfilCliente.html';
          }else { //Si no es cliente, es intructor
            window.location.href = 'perfilInstructor.html'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  if(!bAcceso){
    alert('Credenciales incorrectos');
  }
  return bAcceso;
}
```